# Wrap all created li-elments after click

Tags: jquery, html, events, click, html-lists

```
$('input[name="iplus"]').click(function() {
    $("#billsumary").append("<li>Test</li>");
});
```

I append a li-elemnt on every click. Now I would like to wrap all those created li-elements into an ol-element but not each created one but **all of them together**.

Sample HTML output:

```
<div id='billsumary'>
    <ol>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        ...
        <li>Test</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want do create the `<ol>` at the beginning, and append new elements to it:

```
var ol = $('<ol />').appendTo("#billsumary");

$('input[name="iplus"]').click(function() {  
    $(ol).append("<li>Test</li>");
});
```